# Showing that a set is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $ \Bbb Z[\sqrt 5] = \{a + b\sqrt 5 \mid a, b ∈ \Bbb Z\}$ is an integral domain.

Prove that $ \Bbb Z[\sqrt3i] = \{a + b\sqrt3i \mid a, b ∈ \Bbb Z\}$ is an integral domain.

I understand that in general, I need to show that no zero divisors exist. I believe I also need to first show that these are commutative rings. So my question is, would I take two elements from $ \Bbb Z[\sqrt5]$ say $(a + b\sqrt5)$ and $(c + d\sqrt5)$, then take their product $(a + b\sqrt5)(c + d\sqrt5)$, and then show that $(a + b\sqrt5)(c + d\sqrt5) \neq \sqrt5$  $\forall a,b,c,d \in \Bbb Z$? Then this would imply there are no zero divisors for $ \Bbb Z[\sqrt5]$ so it would be an integral domain.

I am very confused about how to get this started. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of $\sqrt{5}$?

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}]$ are subrings of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: It remains to show the sets are subrings.

Comment: So then I would have to show that both of those are subrings of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Indeed, one has to show that $\forall z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$, $z_1-z_2\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ and $z_1z_2\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ and same things with $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}]$, but I assume you have more or less do that to show they're rings.

Comment: I want to be thorough. Do you know of anywhere, where I can find a proof to show the set of all complex numbers has no zero divisors?

Comment: Good spirit! $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, therefore let $(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $xy=0$ and assume $x\neq 0$, multiplying $xy=0$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ one has $y=0$. Hence, $\mathbb{C}$ has no zero divisors. Now, if you want to show $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, it depends on which definition of $\mathbb{C}$ you have.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $\theta \in \mathbb C$ satisfies a monic quadratic equation $\theta^2=u \theta + v$ with $u,v \in \mathbb Z$, then the set $\mathbb Z[\theta] = \{a + b\theta : a, b \in \mathbb Z\}$ is an integral domain.

Since $\mathbb Z[\theta] \subset \mathbb C$, it suffices to prove that it is a ring, and for that it suffices to prove that it is non-empty and closed under subtraction and multiplication.

Let $z_k = a_k + b_k\theta \in \mathbb Z[\theta]$.

- $z_1-z_2= (a_1-a_2) + (b_1-b_2)\theta \in \mathbb Z[\theta]$.
- $z_1\cdot z_2=(a_1a_2+b_1b_2v) +(a_1b_2+a_2b_1+b_1b_2u)\theta \in \mathbb Z[\theta]$.

This argument can be generalized to monic equations of arbitrary degree.